# How to remove api_key from url in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, api, authorization

I need an apikey to be able to send a get request to a REST api. The request will look something like this -

$http.get(http://api.randomsite.com/page.json?api_key=apikey123)

This will give me data in json format.

But i dont want the api key to appear in the url due to safety reasons. Is it possible to remove the api_key and somehow still make the get request work? Like this -

$http.get(http://api.randomsite.com/page.json)

I read its something to do with headers, but i tried a lot and cannot figure it out. Help :/

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you won't be able to hide the API key. What you could do, is send a request to your server, have your server send a request to said site with the API key as a parameter and then return the response of that request to the original request. You can hide it to not be a part of the GET request, but almost everyone with a little bit of technical knowledge will be able to find the API key.

Comment: Typically you would `POST` in this situation rather than `GET`

Comment: By `POST` you can send the API key in the body.

Comment: Can you explain how by code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to hide the API_KEY, there's few ways to do this

1. Send it through `POST`, although this is only a half measure, as anyone could look into the `POST` body and see what it is. Nevertheless, the way you do it is by

`$http.post("api/salesapi.php/sales/", {API_KEY:xx}, {headers: ... });`

2. Let your server handle it; This hides the API_KEY from the user completely and let the server act as the middle man. But, you need a server to do this, so that's not possible if you're server-less

Comment: I am using MEAN stack so i have a nodejs server. Can you kinda go into a little more detail? That will help, as i am still suck :(